# Flashing an SD card with the dd command - Problem

Tags: ext4, dd

I have a weird problem regarding the `dd` command. I have a `wic` image which has 4 partitions and which I flash onto an sd card with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=<image.wic> of=/dev/sda bs=1M conv=fsync
```

The `lsblk` command correctly shows the 4 partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` - binary
- `/dev/sda2` - ext4
- `/dev/sda3` - binary
- `/dev/sda4` - ext4

Now I mount the `wic` image onto the loop device with the following command:

```
sudo losetup -P /dev/loop19 <image.wic>
```

However, the 2nd and 4th partitions (both `ext4`) of the sd-card and the loop device do not match!? The command

```
sudo cmp /dev/sda2 /dev/loop19p2
```

outputs

```
/dev/sda2 /dev/loop19p2 differ: byte 1069, line 1
```

I googled and apparently the byte 1069 is in superblock, but Ive got no experience what might be wrong. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

PS: None of the partitions are mounted onto a directory, when I compare them! But when I do mount the partitions, the actual files on the partitions match, so its not about the data, but rather about the partition header or whatever comes at the beginning in the ext4 layout.